# Rescue file from broken sd card image

Tags: linux, filesystems

i have installed "armbian" on a sd card for my orange pi. Now i damaged this image so that the pi doesn't start.

On the sd card is a file which is very important. Is there any possibility how i can rescue this file?

Regards

Comment: The image is broken, not the sd card. It's an linux image so i can't read it from a windows computer. Can i only read it from a linux os?

Answer (score 0):

It highly depends on what got corrupted, but assuming, that only some basic metadata (partition layout, filesystem superblock, etc.) got messed up, `testdisk` can rescue a lot of stuff. It's an advanced tool, so you should be careful.

`testdisk` is available on many Linux distros (including Debian). If you don't have Linux on your PC, you might be able to boot from a live CD/DVD/USB-stick and use that (Knoppix comes to mind, but there are other live distros targeting rescue specifically).